# Whats the easiest way to empty and save a Core Data Table in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite, core-data

So I have a entity, which I am treating as a simple Database Table in iOS8 XCODE and SWIFT. I want to delete every entry in the table. Permanently. So when I start up the app again they do not reload.This is my code.

```
func deleteAllItems(){
        println("All Items are being DELETED")
        var count:Int = 0

        while (HBCContactList.count > 0){
            let AppDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let MOContext: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext!
            MOContext.deleteObject(HBCContactList[0] as NSManagedObject)
            HBCContactList.removeAtIndex(0)
            var error:NSError? = nil
            if !MOContext.save(&error){
            abort()
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

It looks like it loads. When its finished on the screen there is nothing in UITableView and all is good. However If I write code to return me the entity via a fetch statement and do a count on the number of records. It still says there is over 150 results.

Thoughts? Am I even in the right ball park?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to fetch the objects and delete them.
Here is an example (make sure you specify your own entity) :

```
// If you'll be using the Managed Object Contexte often,
// you might want to make it a lazy property :
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}()

func deleteData() {
    let context = self.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "yourEntity")
    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false // Only fetch the managedObjectID (not the full object structure)
    if let fetchResults = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [yourEntity] {

        for result in fetchResults {
            context.deleteObject(result)
        }

    }

    var err: NSError?
    if !context.save(&err) {
        println("deleteData - Error : \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        abort()
    } else {
        println("deleteData - Success")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a suggestion for the `NSManagedObjectContext` (i.e. make a lazy property for it) and a line in the delete method `fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false` in order to only fetch the managedObjectID and not the full object structure (i.e. quicker).

Comment: Cheers, Really appreciate this. Learning Swift for the first time and trying to get around the concepts. Your solution fixed my issue directly which was super helpful!